# Api for different tables using sunctum

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables.
1-customer
2-seller
3-affilate

I am fresher for LARAVEL, now i am studying on LARAVEL 8, so i wanted to make login with token api from these tables. Then how can i make please please please help me i am not able to find any proper solutions.

I have added in config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
   'admin' => [
      'driver' => 'session',
      'provider'   => 'admin',
    ],
'affilate' => [
      'driver'  => 'session',
    'provider' =>'affilate',
    ],
   'customer' => [
      'driver'  => 'session',
     'provider' => 'customer',
    ],
   'seller' => [
      'driver'  => 'session',
     'provider' => 'seller',
    ],
],

 'providers' => [
    'admin' => [
     'driver' => 'eloquent',
   'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],
    'customer' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent','model'=>App\Models\Customer::class,
    ],
    'seller' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
  'model' =>App\Models\Seller::class,
    ],
    'affilate' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
  'model' =>App\Models\Affilate::class,
    ],
],
```

Here Is my First Models For Customer

```
<?php
  namespace App\Models;
  use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
  class Customer extends Authenticatable 
   {
      use HasFactory, HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
      protected $table      = 'customer';
      protected $primaryKey = 'id';
      protected $fillable = [
          'name', 'email', 'mobile', 'countryCode','email_verified_at', 
          'email_verified','passWord','confirmPassword'
      ];
      protected $hidden = [
         'passWord', 'remember_token',
     ];
 }
```

Controller For Customer

```
            <?php

        namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

        use Carbon\Carbon;
        use App\Models\Customer;
        use Illuminate\Http\Request;
        use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

        class CustomerController extends Controller
        {    
            public function customerLogin(Request $request)
            {              
                if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt($credentials))
                {
                    $registerCustomer                         =       Auth::Customer();
                    $token                                    =       $registerCustomer->createToken( $registerCustomer->name)->accessToken;
                    $success['success']                       =       true;
                    $success['message']                       =       "Success! you are logged in successfully";
                    $success['token']                         =       $token->plainTextToken;
                    $success['tokenExpiryTime']               =       2592000000; //converted 30days minutes in miliseconds
                    $success['customerName']                  =       $registerCustomer->name;

                    return response()->json(['success' => $success ], $this->successStatus);
                }else {
                    return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
                }
            }
            public function registerCustomer(Request $request)
            {
                $validator              =  Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'name'              => 'required|min:3|max:55',
                    'email'             => 'required|email|unique:customers',
                    'mobile'            => 'required|digits:10|unique:customers',
                    'countryCode'       => 'required|digits:6|unique:customers',
                    'passWord'          => 'required|alpha_num|min:8',
                    'confirmPassword'   => 'required|same:passWord|alpha_num|min:8',
                ]);
                if($validator->fails())
                {
                    return response()->json(['error'=>'Unprocessable Entity','validationErrors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
                }
                $customerData           =  array(
                    'name'              =>    $request->name,
                    'email'             =>    $request->email,
                    'mobile'            =>    $request->mobile,
                    'countryCode'       =>    $request->countryCode,
                    'passWord'          =>    Hash::make($request->passWord),
                    'confirmPassword'   =>    Hash::make($request->confirmPassword),
                    'email_verified'    =>    '0',
                    'email_verified_at' =>    Carbon::now(),
                );
                $saveCustomerData     =  Customer::create($customerData); 
                return $this->customerLogin($request);  
            }
        }
```

And Here Is My Routes

```
<?php
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Api\CustomerController;

    Route::post('/customer/register', [CustomerController::class, 
     'registerCustomer']);
    Route::post('/customer/login', [CustomerController::class, 
    'customerLogin']);
```

I wanted To Know Where is my mistake its Showing Error`ErrorException: Undefined variable $credentials in file`

Thanks Please Please Please Please Please Please  Help Me

Comment: Welcome to SO ...  your error is self explained  `credentials is not defined` you need to define it

Comment: thanks for your responce but i have defined `$credentials = request(['email', 'passWord']);` its returning `{
    "error": "Unauthorised"
}`

Comment: `$request->only('email','password')` this is the right syntax  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-a-portion-of-the-input-data

Comment: i have defined `$credentials = $request->only('email','passWord');` but its shoing same error `{     "error": "Unauthorised" }` can you please check condation is ryt or wrong?

Comment: `passWord` in database should be `password`

Comment: i have changed `passWord` to `password` bur it showing same error

Comment: did that customer table have that  data ?

Comment: yes you can see on controller when customer registered then is login

Comment: then don't use `attempt()` use where condition to find the use once you got user `auth()->login($user)` use to login

Comment: sir can you please write full code i am not able to understand please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this manual method as you told `attempt()` is not working in your case

```php
public function customerLogin(Request $request)
{
    $customer = Customer::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    if (!$customer) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'email not found'], 400);
    }


    if (Hash::check($request->email, $customer->password)) {

        auth()->login($customer);

        $registerCustomer                         =       Auth::user();
        $token                                    =       $registerCustomer->createToken($registerCustomer->name)->accessToken;
        $success['success']                       =       true;
        $success['message']                       =       "Success! you are logged in successfully";
        $success['token']                         =       $token->plainTextToken;
        $success['tokenExpiryTime']               =       2592000000; //converted 30days minutes in miliseconds
        $success['customerName']                  =       $registerCustomer->name;

        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
}
```

Comment: sir it's also showing `{
    "error": "Unauthorised"
}`

Comment: its not goining in if condation

Comment: password is currect i have checked..`    if (Hash::check($request->email, $customer->password)) {
` inside this condation it is not goining

Comment: sir i wanted to every and each user for an personal token for login it is possible in sunctum?? please help

Comment: yes its creating token each tim but when a customer registered and then second customer registered then its login with first customer's token why its going like this i am not understand please help

Comment: i have used code that is given by you.. i am not written any extra code please check here is issue??

Comment: then how can i make authencation with token with individual token to individual user please help i lost my 4 days on this modual.. if you have maded this for multiple tables please send me GitHub link or please suggest me how can i make?? PLZ

Comment: i have protected route like this `Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:customer-api'], function () {
    Route::post('/customer/login', [CustomerController::class, 'customerLogin']);
});`

Comment: i have added this on **config/auth.php** but stiil not working `'customer-api' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customers',
            'hash' => true,
        ],`

Comment: 'driver' => 'token', maded but its not resolved

Comment: are you using vue js ? for token based auth ?

Comment: i am using for reactnative

Comment: then while login your getting token in response store that token in local storage and use that token for protected route

Comment: ok then how we can set token expiry and how to make token expire?? this is ryt way??

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#revoking-mobile-api-tokens

Comment: on this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#revoking-mobile-api-tokens, here mentaioned when user click revoke button, but i wanted to set by default token timing

Comment: `config/sanctum.php` here you can set `expiration`